# How to write to a parent node but not a child in firebase security rules

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I'm using firebase via angularFire. Can anyone help me figure out how the best way to write a new node to /users but then prevent anyone with a different id from writing?

Here's my unfortunate security rules. Was thinking if the data doesn't exist AND there's new data present, that would cover this use case. it doesn't.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "users": {
        ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.exists()",
        "$user": {
            ".write": "auth.uid == $user"
        }
     }
   }  
}
```

Here's the register method that's creating a user and then updating the db:

```
register: function(obj){
            var authRef = new fb(fbRef);
            var authObj = $firebaseAuth(authRef);
            authObj.$createUser({
                email: obj.email,
                password: obj.pass
            }).then(function(userData) {
                console.log("User " + userData.uid + " created successfully!");

                return authObj.$authWithPassword({
                    email: obj.email,
                    password: obj.pass
                });
            }).then(function(authData) {
                var fbObjRef = authRef.child('users');
                var fbObj = $firebaseObject(fbObjRef).$loaded().then(function(data){
                    obj.pass = null;
                    data[authData.uid] = obj;
                    data.$save();
                });
                console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.error("Error: ", error);
            });
        }
```

Somewhere in the threads was mentioned that there's a bug with angularFire but that thread was from 2013. I recall coming across this use case before but cannot find the post. Security rules are the scariest part. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score -2):

I'm open to learning a better way but here's a solution. Basically, I'm able to check if the user's id exists, if not then write is allowed. It's probably not the safest method so feel free to point out my misunderstanding or proper validating :)

```
{
  "rules": {

    ".read": true,
    // ".write": true,
    "users": {
        ".write": "(auth !== null && !root.child('users/'+auth.uid).exists())",
        "$user": {
            ".write": "auth.uid == $user"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your write rule at the users/ level allows anybody who is authenticated to write to any path that doesn't exist. It's also completely superfluous. The `auth.uid === $user` bit under $user/ does everything you need. Test this in the rules simulator tab in your account dashboard for verification. Examples of this in [the security docs for auth](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html)

Comment: The problem with `auth.uid === $user` is that it doesn't allow the user to create their own branch before it exists.. i.e. there is no $user directory yet, how can they write to the parent folder if they're only allowed to write their own branch? I must be overlooking this use case in the docs, would you be a little more specific with these rules if my answer is inappropriete?

Comment: You don't need /users/ to exist in order to write to /users/$user. Have you tried any of this or the examples in the simulator? It should answer your questions here. If there are more constraints or the data structure is more complex than this, start with the Y part of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: Thanks. I know that I can write to $user. It's writing to /users before $user exists is what I want to do only when a new user registers. Sorry if I seem dense and thanks for the help.

Comment: It's fine. It's just a matter of figuring out what you're trying to accomplish, which is still unclear. Writing what to /users? Writing a user record, as in /users/$user/<data>? Or something else? What is it you're attempting to write here?